# Can we create an alert on a singlestat

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

Can we create an alert on a singlestat? I don't see an "alert tab" to create an alert. Can you please suggest me a way to compare two singlestat from 2 data sources.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, you cannot define alert on Singlestat.
Future request is still open: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6983

As of Grafana version 2.5 you can create Panels which can query multiple datasource at once. You just need to switch the Data Source into `--Mixed--` mode.

You can try it here: https://play.grafana.org/d/000000014/elasticsearch-metrics?panelId=4&fullscreen&edit

Comment: I think I'm missing something.. I don't understand how using a panel with mixed datasources is relevant to alerting on a singlestat. Can you explain? I'd like to find a workaround for this.